# Why is this JSON giving null values when I deserialize and try to extract values

Tags: json, scala, apache-kafka, deserialization, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using Spark Structured Streaming to consume messages sent from a few Kafka topics. The json string is structured like this and I want to extract 'created_at', 'text' and 'tag':

```
{"data":
  {"created_at":"***",
   "id":"***",
   "text":"***"},
 "matching_rules":
   [{"id":"***",
     "tag":"***"}]
}
```

I wrote the following schema:

```
val DFschema = StructType(Array(
      StructField("data", StructType(Array(
        StructField("created_at", TimestampType),
        StructField("text", StringType)))),
      StructField("matching_rules", StructType(Array(
        StructField("tag", StringType)
      )))
    ))
```

When I use the schema with *from_json*() I can successfully extract 'created_at' and 'text' as columns with non-null values using *getField*(), but when I try to do the same for 'tag' its column is populated with nulls:

```
val kafkaDF: DataFrame = spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", servers)
      .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
      .option("subscribe", topics)
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
      .load()
      .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
      .select(col("key"), from_json($"value", DFschema).alias("structdata"))
      .select($"key",
        $"structdata.data".getField("created_at").alias("created_at"),
        $"structdata.data".getField("text").alias("text"),
        $"structdata.matching_rules".getField("tag").alias("topic")
      )
      .withColumn("hour", date_format(col("created_at"), "HH"))
      .withColumn("date", date_format(col("created_at"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

Looking at the json I see that 'id' and 'tag' are wrapped in square brackets and this leads me to suspect I've left out a datatype in the schema, but I'm not experienced enough to know what. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arrays, you have to wrap your `StructType` with `ArrayType` as below:

```scala
val DFschema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("data", StructType(Array(
    StructField("created_at", TimestampType),
    StructField("id", StringType),
    StructField("text", StringType)))),
  StructField("matching_rules", ArrayType(StructType(Array(
    StructField("tag", StringType),
    StructField("id", StringType))
  ))))
)
```

Another alternative is to use (under the assumption that `content` is your column):

```scala
ds = ds.withColumn("content", 
  expr("from_json(content, 'STRUCT<data:STRUCT<created_at:STRING,id:STRING,text:STRING>,matching_rules:ARRAY<STRUCT<id:STRING,tag:STRING>>>')")
)
```

You can ask Spark to generate the schema through `schema_of_json`.

Good luck!